# How to write conditions based on user capabilities not on user role?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

How to write conditions on capabilities not on user role?

Comment: Capabilities are far easier to test than user roles. How were you testing user roles?

Comment: I was implementing that in a plugin and was getting error, added if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) { include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); } above that and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [current_user_can()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/), or [$user->has_cap()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/has_cap/) for other users:.

```php
if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_post', $post_id ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to move this item to the Trash.' ) );
}
```